# How to delete a table line in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I`ve got a problem to delete items from object.
I made a function for deleting,but unfortunetly it can only delete 1 number in object.Like if i have 2 tasks and i choose to delete 2nd it will delete 1st one.
No idea how to fix it:(

```
 $scope.deleteTask = function(taskIndex){
    $scope.tasks.splice(taskIndex,1);
}
```

Here`s another code blocks for easier understanding of my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
   </td>
   <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="statusCheck"> </td>
   <td style="{{setStyleToTd(statusCheck)}}">{{statusChecker(statusCheck)}}</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
</tr>

var taskInformation = [
{
    taskName: "Test task"
    , status: false
    }
];
```

(I know there are lots of problems like mine but I didnt find a proper answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the id of the task not the task itself, try:

```
ng-click="deleteTask($index)"
```

Comment: omg man, what a simply correct answer:) Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 1):

It's better send object instead of index for delete. It should be like this

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>

$scope.deleteTask = function(task){
   var taskIndex  = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
   $scope.tasks.splice(taskIndex,1);
}
```